# When voting to close as a duplicate of an unanswered question, the wording of the auto-comment "Does this answer your question?" makes no sense

Tags: discussion, status-declined, comments, vote-to-close, exact-duplicates

Currently, when voting to close a question as a duplicate of another question, the system automatically posts a comment in the following format:

> Does this answer your question? [link]

However, this wording is somewhat out-of-sync at times. I have just now voted to close a duplicate question because the OP posted an essentially identical question; however, neither of the questions had answers.

In case anyone has suggestions for a better phrase, throw them out there.

Comment: thats a good point but I do not think we mods can change that automatic text, I added status review tag to it so some SE staff can take a note there is demand for this, but I doubt they would change it just for one site

Comment: Semi-related MSE posts: [The auto-comment “Does this answer your question?” generated when voting to close as a duplicate is sometimes confusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339563/335251), [New duplicate automatic comment makes literally zero sense when voting to close as a duplicate of an unanswered question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340009/335251) – The former is [status-declined] with [this answer by Yaakov](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343285/335251).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an edge-case – unless you're a mod, you can only close a question as a duplicate of a question with no upvoted or accepted answers if both questions were posted by the same author (as noted in [this FAQ on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/335251)). Otherwise, regular users can't close a question as a duplicate of an unanswered one in the first place.

As I mentioned in the comments, there have been some similar posts on MSE asking for a change to the wording of this comment. In particular, [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339563/335251) was marked as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), with [this explanation by Yaakov](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343285/335251) that the wording of the automated comment is, by and large, accomplishing its intended goal. This particular edge-case doesn't seem to justify making a change to this wording.